# Is the Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR) integrated in .NET 4.6 & C#6?

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-6.0

I heard a lot of thing about DLR 4-5 years ago but now nobody is talking about it.
I searched a lot about it on web but didn’t find any recent blogs on it.

As we know Roslyn is the default compiler not CSC in Visual Studio 2015 to compile C# code so my question is: Does Roslyn use the DLR concept or it is gone completely?

Comment: It was integrated into System.Core 6 years ago.  Microsoft.CSharp has the binder.  Assemblies that are automatically added to any new project that targets .NET 4.0 or higher.  It just doesn't make a lot of noise, it is normal now.  Use the *dynamic* keyword or the DynamicObject class in your code.

Comment: I think this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052(v=vs.110).aspx) be helpful. and Also refer [link](http://dlr.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Reasons why it isn't often talked about is that its very situational. It is very powerful, but in normal projects not very useful too often. It can be very useful searching for values in anonymously deserialized json dumps, etc. when you dont know the full structure of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is integrated into the `Microsoft.CSharp` namespace (has its dynamic binder there), and even has it's own keyword in C#.

When you create a project in Visual Studio with .NET 4 or higher, you can simply use the `dynamic` keyword to use parts the DLR.